# how to fix Error: Call to a member function connection() on null in Laravel 7.xx PHPunit?

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-7

I duplicated the `.env` file of laravel and named it into `.env.testing`
inside the `.env.testing` file I have

```
DB_CONNECTION=sqlite
DB_DATABASE="C:/wamp64/wwww/myApp/test.sqlite"
```

then in the `phpunit.xml` i have this

```
<php>
    <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
    <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <server name="DB_DATABASE" value="C:/wamp64/www/myApp/test.sqlite"/>
    <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
    <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
    <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
</php>
```

is my settings correct ?

In my test class I have this code

```
namespace Tests\Unit;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
class CodeTest extends TestCase
{

    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function test_can_push_data() {

           $this->assertTrue(true);
    }

}
```

When I tried to run

```
./vendor/bin/phpunit

1) Tests\Unit\CodeTest::test_can_push_data
Error: Call to a member function connection() on null
```

Any Idea why?

Comment: Does the problem happen if you comment out the `use` statement in the beginning of the class?

Comment: It happens wether there is use statement or none

Comment: Can you try to run with xdebug? Then you should see a stacktrace, that might be helpful

Comment: Just to make sure I got this right: if you remove the `use DatabaseMigrations;`, you still get the same error? In that case, could you please share the whole `phpunit.xml`?